# How to escape to LaTeX inside \lstinline?

Tags: listings, matlab-prettifier

The escape character works inside `lstlisting` environment but not inside `\lstinline`

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{matlab-inline}{
    style=Matlab-editor, 
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\mlttfamily\color{DodgerBlue3},
    escapechar=",
}

% END_FOLD

\lstset{style=matlab-inline}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=frame]

    \begin{lstlisting}
    text "$e = m c^{2}$"
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    \lstinline|text "$e = m c^{2}$"|

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO `\lstinline` does not support escape characters, because you can end inline code, wherever you want and restart it again after the LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{matlab-inline}{
    style=Matlab-editor, 
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\mlttfamily\color{DodgerBlue3},
    escapechar=",
}

% END_FOLD

\lstset{style=matlab-inline}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=frame]

    \begin{lstlisting}
    text "$e = m c^{2}$"
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    \lstinline|text |$\mathcolor{DodgerBlue3}{e = m c^{2}}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]